# JavaScript hide another element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, hide, onmouseover, onmouseout

So I have this JavaScript I am working on, and I want to show/hide another HTML element on mouseover but it wont work.
Here's The HTML:

```
<div class='post' onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName('another_element').style.display='inline';" onmouseout="document.getElementsByClassName('another_element').style.display='none';">
```

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason not to, I would suggest using a JS library like jQuery as it makes things like this a LOT easier.  Plus they deal with any cross browser issues you may come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a thought, and found a simple solution. Thanks all of you guys for your contributions. Here's what I came up with. I can set a unique id to each element I am going to show/hide, and use getElementById for each one instead of using the getElementsByClassName and having to loop through the array. So It ends up like this:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('an_element').style.display='inline'; document.getElementById('another_element').style.display='inline';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('an_element').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('another_element').style.display='none';"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class='post' onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName('another_element')[0].style.display='inline';" onmouseout="document.getElementsByClassName('another_element')[0].style.display='none';">
```

It doesn't work because getElementsByClassName() retrieves an array of elements that contain `another` class. You just have select which element you want.

If the element is only one, you could give it a certain id, like this:

```
<div id="another_element"></div>

<div class='post' onmouseover="document.getElementById('another_element').style.display='inline';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('another_element').style.display='none';">
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array. Try iterating over them.

Comment: I want all the elements with the specified class to have this JavaScript applied to them so could someone show me how to iterate through them or some other easier way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use jQuery. Then, write a `delegate` to assign all elements which match a selector to be assigned an event listener. It's pretty simple once you start digging into javascript event listeners and such and try to understand how it works. If you're interested, I can show you a demo in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not a `Node`. A `NodeList` does not have a style property.  You can either use the first element in the list only, or you could select by ID instead:

```
<div class='post' onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName('another_element')[0].style.display='inline';" onmouseout="document.getElementsByClassName('another_element')[0].style.display='none';">

<div class='post' onmouseover="document.getElementsById('another_element').style.display='inline';" onmouseout="document.getElementsById('another_element').style.display='none';">
```

Obviously in the second example you need to give the element an ID...